# books with a focus on .NET framework and not so much with a focus on the language used

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

i'm learning vb.net and c# at the moment. can anyone recommend a book that focuses on the .NET framework in general and isn't too language specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are looking for broad knowledge I liked .NET Framework Essentials http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003029/

Comment: Agreed, this is an underrated book; too bad they haven't updated it for the latest .net versions

Comment: i found this book on amazon in a 3rd edition print. the link above is for the 2nd edition. if i were to buy this book i should get the 3rd edition print right? thanks.

Comment: It makes sense to get the latest version. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The training kits for the .NET framework certifications were pretty good.  Have a look at [http://www.amazon.com/MCTS-Self-Paced-Training-Exam-70-536/dp/0735626197](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626197).  There's newer versions now (I think), but its targetted at learning the framework, and has examples in both C# and VB.NET.

Comment: i didn't think to look at the certification books. the best java book i've ever read was a java certification prep book (scjp; kathy sierra). thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest microsft publication book for .net framework. Also you can go for Apress pro series if you have good understanding of .net fx